# In the pH system of acids and bases, are there 10^-7 loose ions per liter (at pH of 7) or per mole of solvent? (Or per mole of total substance?)

Tags: acid-base, ph

Most places tell me that the number on the pH scale tells you the number of dissociated ions, in moles, per liter of substance.    But, Wikipedia's article [pH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PH#Definition_and_measurement) says this....:

> ... For a commonplace example based on the facts that the masses of a mole of water, a mole of hydrogen ions, and a mole of hydroxide ions are respectively 18 g, 1 g, and 17 g, a quantity of $10^7$ moles of pure (pH 7) water, or 180 tonnes ($18\times10^7$ g), contains close to 1 g of dissociated hydrogen ions (or rather 19 g of H3O+ hydronium ions) and 17 g of hydroxide ions.

But, if there are 10^-7 moles of hydrogen cations (protons) per LITER, and one mole of protons is approximately one gram (as Wiki's example says), then there is one mole (one gram) of protons per 10^7 liters of water, right?  One gram of hydrogen cations per 10,000,000 liters?
As opposed to what Wiki says, claiming one gram of loose hydrogen ions per 180 tonnes of water?

(One liter of water weighs about one kilogram, and there are a thousand kilograms in a tonne, correct?)

EDIT: Wiki's section on pH and all the incorrect numbers have been corrected.

Comment: Wikipedia certainly has errors, but typically they catch the most glaring ones.  And saying that 18 g/mol x 107 mols = 180 tonnes is a pretty glaring error, so I'm suprised that would be in Wikipedia. Thus please provide a link to the Wikipedia reference so we can see what is going on.

Comment: But if the Wikipedia page is saying pH 7=> 10^-7 moles H+/(mole H2O), that would be wrong, since pH 7 => 10^-7 moles H+/(L H2O) =10^-7 moles H+/(55.6 L H2O), b/c 1 L H2O = 1000g/(18 g/mol) = 55.6 mol H2O

Comment: Think this through:  1. How can there be a *fraction* of an ion? What is 1/2 ion, or 1/10,000,000  [10^-7] ion? 2.Start with Avogadro's Number: There are ~6*10^23 molecules/mole.

Comment: I added the source of the quote to the question. I also did multiple edits to correct the formatting of the exponents in the text.

Answer (score 2):

> In the pH system of acids and bases, are there 10^-7 loose ions per
> liter (at pH of 7) or per mole of solvent? (Or per mole of total
> substance?)

In a rigorous sense none of the options is correct, because pH being approximated by molarity is an approximation itself. The problem lies in the measurement itself and pH should be

$$pH= -log (a_{H^+})$$

The pH probe "senses" the activity of hydrogen ions not the molarity. This is why the pH of 5 M HCl is not equal to $$pH= -log (5)$$

There are no free or loose hydrogen ions in water, like a bare proton, rather this proton is attached to a network of water molecules.

Wiki is talking about an *approximation*. 1 ton is equal 1000,000 grams, so 10$^7$ mole/g x 18 g $\ce{H2O}$ is indeed 180 t. This part is correct so far. Note the author must be following metric ton. The whole world does not follow the US ton.

1 liter of water weighs ~ 1000 grams. Then 1000 g water contains 10$^{-7}$ moles of $\ce{H+}$, and 18x10$^{7}$ g water should have 1.8 x 10$^{-2}$ mol $\ce{H+}$ or 0.018 g $\ce{H+}$. I don't get 1 g.

Answer (score 1):

To settle the basic question, at 25 °C there are $10^{-7}$ moles of $\ce{H+}$  and $\ce{OH-}$ ions per liter of pure water. The value of the ionization constant of liquid water depends on the temperature of course.

The cited sentence jams so much together that the sentence is extremely poorly constructed.

Comment: The verbatim quote in Wikipedia is plagiarized from an engineering book (or vice versa), called Engineering Chemistry by Nicky Rutledge, 2018. It has the same mistake, as in Wikipedia. Does 180 ton of water have 1 g $\ce{H+}$ ions? I get 0.018 g rather.

Comment: Yes, the article's math is right. Remember that a liter of water is about 55 molar.

Comment: Yes, but what is the omission here? 1 liter of water weighs ~ 1000 grams. Then 1000 g water contains 10$^{-7}$ moles of $\ce{H+}$, and 18x10$^{7}$ g water should have 1.8 x 10$^{-2}$ mol $\ce{H+}$ or 0.018 g $\ce{H+}$.

Comment: @M.Farooq - You are correct. I was multiplying 10^7 moles of H2O times 10^-7 molar for H+ to get 1 gram of H+ ions. But that is wrong. You need 10^7 liters of water to get 1 gram of H+ ions. So there is a fundamental mistake in the math in the sentence as you pointed out.

Comment: I was also wondering if both the book and Wiki can make such a mistake.

Comment: The [00:44, 26 May 2016 edit](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=PH&oldid=722102676#Definition_and_measurement) of the Wikipedia article does not have the exact sentence, but the next edit by Vaughan Pratt (talk | contribs) at [01:02, 26 May 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=PH&oldid=722104667#Definition_and_measurement) does. So it would seem that Rutledge plagiarized the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Someone should correct the Wikipedia section. The 180 ton part is fine. The rest is wrong.

Comment: The sentence is just ludicrous. It is supposed to be a "commonplace example." Who can really imagine 180 metric tons of water?

Comment: I corrected that Wiki section so that it does not confuse the rest and reach the books.